# Contact Form submitted email styling

Tags: email, phpmailer

I’m using Top Studio’s Contact Form Generator v 2.7.

Is there a way to make the labels in the email bold in the *class.phpmailer.php* file?

Ex:

**Name:** John

**Number:** 555-5555-5555

Answer (score 0):

PHPMailer has no input into what your messages look like. You need to build a message body in HTML and put it in `Body`:

```
$mail->Body = "<p><strong>Name</strong>: John</p><p><strong>Number</strong>: 555-5555-5555</p>";
```

You should not edit the library files - you don't need to to achieve what you want.

Comment: I apologize, but which file and where do I use this code? I’m not that well-versed in PHP development.
Thank you.

Comment: PHPMailer is a library, and as such does nothing by itself - you need to call it from a script and ask it to do stuff. All the provided examples do this, and you should base your code on one of them.

Comment: I’m afraid I’m still lost. Can you suggest a resource?

Comment: The contact form generator plugin will be using PHPMailer, and it's in in there that you will need to amend it because it's only there that the form submission data will be available and be used to configure the message body. If you're not up to editing that (and I recommend you don't as it will break your ability to apply updates to the plugin), I suggest you live without it as this is purely a cosmetic change, or find another plugin that has styling features. If you're a beginner at this, editing Wordpress plugins isn't a good place to start as it's extremely messy and complex!

Comment: I have the standalone version, not the WordPress version. Would it still be possible to make the edits?

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to make your changes in the form generator, not PHPMailer. I suggest you read the support docs for the form generator for how best to alter it, or open a support request with them.